# ASP.net 4.5 / Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I want to set up forms authentication in my asp.net site. I have created one from a blank template in visual studio. I already have a database setup but it doesnt have any user tables. All of the reference material that I am able to find online is either for very old asp versions (which I assume things have changed) or tell you to use the visual studio templates. I want to know how to add this stuff to my current project and am hoping someone has good reference recommendations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Jon Galloway's [SimpleMembership, Membership Providers, Universal Providers and the new ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC 4 templates](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)